# Subtracting values from a variable until that variable is 0 Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel, user-defined-functions

I'm doing work to automate a ledger of mine based on the FIFO accounting principle (First in First out), where anything that would be referred to as a contra balance would be subtracted from the first entry, then the second, until that variable is zero (or if there is residual begin a new accounting line).

Generally what I have been doing to add a new position to this ledger (not removing any balance simply creating a line item is this...

```
Tickerstring = TTB 'TTB is the user defined input for the ticker

tickercolumn = HBWS.Cells.Find(What:="Ticker").Column 'Use this to identify 
what column the ticker field is

Set TickerResult = HBWS.Cells.Find(What:=TickerString, LookIn:=xlValues)
If Not TickerResult Is Nothing Then
tickerRow = TickerResult.Row
Else
End If 'Identifies the row which the actual Ticker is in i.e. the TTB

HBWS.Cells(tickerRow, tickercolumn) = TTB
```

I use that same concept to define the amount of Shares, and whether they are long and short. Inserting Userform inputs into the respective cells.

My question is, say I run that code 3 times and now have 3 lines items that look like this

AAPL  300  Long

AAPL  100  Long

AAPL  100  Long

Then I want to add a new position for 600 short, which would go through the FIFO accounting process and remove 300 from the first row, 100 from the second, 100 from the third, then create a new line with the 100 short. How would I go about doing that?

I would imagine that I would be subtracting from a user defined variable i.e take 300 out of the first row, now my defined variable is left at 300 (when it started at 600).

Basically i think the best way to describe this would be how do I subtract from a variable based on current workbook values, then continue using this in my sub procedure.

EDIT: Editing my post for clarity

i have the following entry in my spreadsheet

[image]

I want to run my macro to take my short position indicated in the below userform subtract it from currently in my spread sheet then create a residual line representing what is left in the short position

[image]

The end state should look like this

[image]

Let me know if you need additional info

Comment: Your question is rather unclear. Please [edit] to clarify what the problem is. See if reading [mcve] helps.

Comment: Could please add a screenshot with more relevant lines, to help understand the request, i.e. some data before any input, some input lines, and the expected outcome after processing the input lines.

Comment: Done & Done added more screenshots and clear description @MathieuGuindon

Comment: Let me know if that more clear @EEM

Comment: The first table and the second table are the same table (before & after), so the table is meant to show only the end position? Or you have two separated tables?

Comment: `Date&Time Booked` is a numeric TimeStamp? Are you using a ListObject (excel table) or just a range with formulas?

Answer (score 1):

**Requirements:**

1. Maintain a ledger of shares transactions, generated from an user form input *(one at a time)*.
2. Calculate & show the net position of the shares, using the FIFO inventory valuation method.

**Proposed Solution:**
The requirements can be achieved using:

1. A `ListObject` to contain the ledger of transactions and to calculate the end position after each transaction.
2. A `PivotTable` to show the end position of the shares *(and any other report needed)*.

The figure below shows the proposed `ListObject` and `PivotTable`

[image]

**ListObject Fields:**

*Input from user form*

- ***Ticker        :*** Share symbol.
- ***L/S       :*** Share position (Long\Short).
- ***Lots      :*** Quantity of shares.

*Calculated by VBA procedure*

- ***L/S.Net:*** Net share position (Long\Short).
- ***Qty:*** Net share quantity (absolute value).
- ***Lots.Net:*** Net share quantity.
- ***T:*** Record Type (P: Prior \ R: Residual), used to flag the latest transaction of a share.
- ***TimeStamp:*** Record date & time of posting, used to apply the FIFO valuation method.

**VBA Procedure:**
*See explanations\coments inserted in the procedure.*

```
Option Private Module
Option Compare Text
Option Explicit
Option Base 1
Rem Updated 20180504_121918

Sub ListObject_Stocks_Ledger_FIFO(vRcrd As Variant)
Dim aFlds As Variant, vFld As Variant
aFlds = [{"Ticker","L/S","Lots","T","TimeStamp","Lots.Net","L/S.Net","Qty"}]
Dim lo As ListObject, pt As PivotTable
Dim sTicker As String, lCnt As Long, lPos As Long
Dim lRow As Long, bCol As Byte, b As Byte
Dim sFml As String
Dim vValue As Variant
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Rem Set Objects
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sht(0)")      'change as required
        Application.Goto .Cells(1), 1
        Set pt = .PivotTables("ptPositions")
        Set lo = .ListObjects("loPositions")
    End With

    With lo

        Rem Set ListObject New Row
        lRow = 1 + .ListRows.Count
        Select Case lRow
        Case 1
            Rem ListObject with zero records
            .HeaderRowRange.Cells(2, 1).Value2 = "!NEW"

        Case Else
            vFld = "Ticker"
            sTicker = vRcrd(1)
            bCol = .ListColumns(vFld).Index
            lCnt = WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(.DataBodyRange.Columns(bCol), sTicker)

            Rem Flag prior Ticker records
            Select Case lCnt
            Case 0
                Rem New Ticker - NO ACTION

            Case 1
                Rem Ticker with only one prior record
                lPos = WorksheetFunction.Match(sTicker, .DataBodyRange.Columns(bCol), 0)
                .ListColumns("T").DataBodyRange.Cells(lPos).Value2 = "P"

            Case Else
                Rem Ticker with only one prior record
                .Range.AutoFilter Field:=bCol, Criteria1:=sTicker
                .ListColumns("T").DataBodyRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Value2 = "P"
                .Range.AutoFilter

        End Select: End Select

        Rem Add New Record
        For Each vFld In aFlds
            b = 1 + b
            bCol = .ListColumns(vFld).Index

            Rem Set Field Value\Formula
            sFml = vbNullString
            vValue = vbNullString
            Select Case vFld
            Case "Ticker", "L/S", "Lots":   vValue = vRcrd(b)
            Case "T":                       vValue = "R"
            Case "TimeStamp":               vValue = CDbl(Now)
            Case "L/S.Net"
                sFml = "=IF(NOT(EXACT([@T],'R')),CHAR(39)," & vbLf _
                    & "IF([@[Lots.Net]]<0,'Short',IF([@[Lots.Net]]>0,'Long','Zero')))"

            Case "Qty"
                sFml = "=IF(NOT(EXACT([@T],'R')),CHAR(39)," & vbLf _
                    & "ABS([@[Lots.Net]]))"

            Case "Lots.Net"
                sFml = "=IF(NOT(EXACT([@T],'R')),CHAR(39),SUM(" & vbLf _
                    & "SUMIFS([Lots],[Ticker],[@Ticker],[L/S],'Long',[TimeStamp],'<='&[@TimeStamp])," & vbLf _
                    & "-SUMIFS([Lots],[Ticker],[@Ticker],[L/S],'Short',[TimeStamp],'<='&[@TimeStamp])))"

            End Select

            Rem Apply Field Value\Formula
            Select Case vbNullString
            Case Is <> vValue
                .DataBodyRange.Cells(lRow, bCol).Value2 = vValue

            Case Is <> sFml
                sFml = Replace(sFml, Chr(39), Chr(34))
                With .DataBodyRange.Columns(bCol)
                    .Formula = sFml
                    .Value2 = .Value2

    End With: End Select: Next: End With

    Rem Sort ListObject
    With lo.Sort
        With .SortFields
            .Clear
            .Add Key:=lo.ListColumns("Ticker").DataBodyRange, _
                SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
            .Add Key:=lo.ListColumns("TimeStamp").DataBodyRange, _
                SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
        End With
        .Header = xlYes
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With

    Rem Refresh PivotTable
    pt.PivotCache.Refresh

    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    End Sub
```

Use this procedure to simulate the posting from the user form:

```
Sub ListObject_Stocks_Ledger_FIFO_TEST()
Dim aDATA As Variant, vRcrd As Variant
aDATA = Array( _
    Array("AAPL", "Long", "300"), _
    Array("AAPL", "Long", "100"), _
    Array("AAPL", "Long", "100"), _
    Array("AAPL", "Short", "600"), _
    Array("BCS", "Long", "300"), _
    Array("BCS", "Long", "100"), _
    Array("BCS", "Short", "500"), _
    Array("Test", "Long", "100"), _
    Array("Test", "Long", "200"), _
    Array("Test", "Long", "300"), _
    Array("Test", "Short", "400"))

    For Each vRcrd In aDATA
        Call ListObject_Stocks_Ledger_FIFO(vRcrd)
: Stop
    Next

    End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

This could be an example of what you want to do, hopefully is usefull to you:

```
Sub test()

Dim reduce_amount As String
reduce_amount = Val(InputBox("Number:"))

Dim cell As Range

For Each cell In Selection

cell_value = Mid(cell.Value, 6, 3)

If IsNumeric(cell_value) Then
    reduce_amount = reduce_amount - cell_value
End If

Next cell

If reduce_amount > 0 Then
 Selection.End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0).Value = "AAPL " & reduce_amount & " Long"
End If

End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: So I think i explained the situation a bit poorly but you answer may be quite close.

The data is separated in a few columns I'll post a screenshot.

Comment: added a picture, also my concern is making sure when the all of the cells eventually reach zero that the residual balance is retained in the variable.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should make it so each transaction stands on it's own (unless you have a good reason to do it otherwise). I never store "state" in a cell if possible. What about keeping track of each bucket. Here's an example

```
Public Sub AddLots(ByVal Ticker As String, ByVal Lot As Double)

    Dim rCell As Range
    Dim LotRemains As Double
    Dim dc As Scripting.Dictionary
    Dim dToTake As Double
    Dim ThisTicker As String, ThisLS As String, ThisLot As Double, ThisBucket As Long, ThisTotal As Double
    Dim lo As ListObject
    Dim aOutput() As Variant
    Dim MaxBucket As Long
    Dim i As Long

    LotRemains = Lot
    Set dc = New Scripting.Dictionary
    Set lo = Sheet1.ListObjects(1)

    For Each rCell In lo.ListColumns(1).DataBodyRange.Cells
        'Store this row's values
        ThisTicker = rCell.Value: ThisLS = rCell.Offset(0, 1).Value: ThisLot = rCell.Offset(0, 2).Value
        ThisBucket = rCell.Offset(0, 3).Value: ThisTotal = rCell.Offset(0, 4).Value

        'if the ticker is the same
        If ThisTicker = Ticker Then
            'if it's going the opposite way of our transaction
            If (Lot > 0 And ThisLS = "Short") Or _
                (Lot < 0 And ThisLS = "Long") Then

                'if there's still something left in the bucket
                If ThisTotal <> 0 Then
                    If Abs(ThisTotal) >= Abs(LotRemains) Then
                        dToTake = LotRemains
                    Else
                        dToTake = -ThisTotal
                    End If
                    'store this bucket
                    dc.Add ThisTicker & "|" & ThisBucket, dToTake
                    'reduce the amount left to test
                    LotRemains = LotRemains - dToTake
                    'stop looking if we've used it all up
                    If LotRemains = 0 Then Exit For
                End If
            End If
        End If
    Next rCell

    'this is an array we'll write out to the worksheet
    ReDim aOutput(1 To dc.Count + IIf(LotRemains <> 0, 1, 0), 1 To 4)

    'for every bucket we saved, put it in the array
    For i = 1 To dc.Count
        aOutput(i, 1) = Ticker
        aOutput(i, 2) = IIf(Lot > 0, "Long", "Short")
        aOutput(i, 3) = Abs(dc.Items(i - 1))
        aOutput(i, 4) = Split(dc.Keys(i - 1), "|")(1)
    Next i

    'if we couldn't use it all up, get the next bucket number
    If LotRemains <> 0 Then
        For Each rCell In lo.ListColumns(1).DataBodyRange.Cells
            If rCell.Value = Ticker Then
                If rCell.Offset(0, 3).Value > MaxBucket Then
                    MaxBucket = rCell.Offset(0, 3).Value
                End If
            End If
        Next rCell

        'then add a new bucket to the array
        aOutput(dc.Count + 1, 1) = Ticker
        aOutput(dc.Count + 1, 2) = IIf(Lot > 0, "Long", "Short")
        aOutput(dc.Count + 1, 3) = Abs(LotRemains)
        aOutput(dc.Count + 1, 4) = MaxBucket + 1
    End If

    'write out the new transactions to the worksheet
    lo.ListRows.Add.Range.Resize(UBound(aOutput, 1), UBound(aOutput, 2)).Value = aOutput

End Sub
```

Start here

[image]

Then run `AddLots "BCS", 400` and get

[image]

Then run `AddLots "BCS", -1000` and get

[image]

Then use a pivot table to see where you are by ticker, by bucket, or whatever

[image]

The formula in the last column of the table is

```
=SUMPRODUCT(([Ticker]=[@Ticker])*([Bucket]=[@Bucket])*([LS]="Long")*([Lots]))-SUMPRODUCT(([Ticker]=[@Ticker])*([Bucket]=[@Bucket])*([LS]="Short")*([Lots]))
```

Comment: That was actually one of my first ideas!, kind of taking a T account approach to the situation, where you have debits and credits removing from each other.

I'm trying to treat it more as a running inventory though than a ledger. I want to be able to see the active "book" of a running lists of stocks.

So in concept I should never have a short and a long position under the same bucket. Though your solution is definitely a legitimate and quite smart answer

Answer (score -1):

I looked at all of the answers posted and took a few ideas from each. I used the below code to control the variable and then I have other code that kind of compiles everything using the final variable.

The section of code that clears out the other lots though and defines the variable is below

```
Dim rCell As Range
Dim reduce_amount As Variant
Dim HBWS As Worksheet
Dim TickerTotalString As String
TickerTotalString = "Total " & TTB
Set HBWS = Sheets("Hedgebook")
Dim FormulaWS As Worksheet
Set FormulaWS = Sheets("Formula_Template")

LastHBR = HBWS.Cells(HBWS.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
ClastHBC = HBWS.Cells(3, HBWS.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
LastFWSR = FormulaWS.Cells(FormulaWS.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
CLASTFWSC = FormulaWS.Cells(3, FormulaWS.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column


Tickercolumn = HBWS.Cells.Find(What:="Ticker").Column
Datecolumn = HBWS.Cells.Find(What:="Date&Time Booked").Column
LScolumn = HBWS.Cells.Find(What:="L/S").Column
Lotscolumn = HBWS.Cells.Find(What:="Lots").Column
Conversioncolumn = HBWS.Cells.Find(What:="Conversion Cents").Column
Borrowcolumn = HBWS.Cells.Find(What:="Borrow (bps)").Column

Set Tickerresult = HBWS.Cells.Find(What:=TickerTotalString, LookIn:=xlValues)
If Not Tickerresult Is Nothing Then
Tickerrow = Tickerresult.Row
Else
End If

reduce_amount = LTB 'Userform input that defines the total lots



If reduce_amount > 0 Then
For Each rCell In HBWS.Range(Cells(3, Tickercolumn), Cells(LastHBR, Tickercolumn))
    If rCell.Value = TTB And rCell.Offset(0, -1).Value <> TickerTotalString And reduce_amount > 0 Then
    Cell_value = rCell.Offset(0, 3).Value
        If reduce_amount < Cell_value Then
        rCell.Offset(0, 3).Value = Cell_value - reduce_amount
        ElseIf reduce_amount > Cell_value Then
        rCell.Offset(0, 3).Value = 0
        reduce_amount = reduce_amount - Cell_value
        ElseIf reduce_amount = Cell_value Then
        reduce_amount = 0
        rCell.Offset(0, 3).Value = 0
        End If
    End If
Next
End If
```